# Can I make Vim adept to different colorscheme based on "power source", "monitor output"?

Tags: laptop, vim

### Description of the challenge/use-case

Upon switching to a new laptop with fancy CPU but crappy monitor, I would like to restrict `background` to "dark" when I am using the laptop on the go. However, I am spending most of the time having the laptop docked and thereby using my normal set of monitors.

Here goes my usual setting that adapts `background` to the time of the day: `dark` when it is night, and `light` when it is during the days. I could have refined it better, but it is working just fine.

```
if has("gui_running")
    " My time-keeper and eye-saver
    if strftime("%H") < 6  
        set background=dark
    elseif strftime("%H") >18
        set background=dark
    else
        set background=light
    endif
else
    set background=dark
endif
```

### Question:

1. Is there a conditional that I can call/specify to indicate the displaying monitor?
2. Or, say, a conditional that reflects the status of the power source?

### Potential solution (pending implementation)

1. As @[Heptite](https://superuser.com/users/10779/heptite) has suggested, a Windows command-line tool that returns something about the system shall do the trick. Here goes the closest hit that can do the trick:

   - To report/print/display the screen resolution of the "current" monitor:

     - Source: https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/issues/354
     - The command: `wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution`
   - I tried to run `!wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution` through the command-line native to Vim, but an additional Command Prompt window pops up.
   - **Formal Solution (pending)**: this screen should serve as a good identifier for the condition in which the laptop is on its tiny `1366 * 768` monitor.
2. There shall be another way to identify the battery source, but I was not able to reproduce anything close to the screen-resolution identification as shown above.

Comment: Is there an operating system command or library call that could give you the necessary information for your conditional tests?

Comment: Oh, are you suggesting that there is some external command that is executable through Vim's command-line? I have no idea how Windows operates at the command-line level. [More likely, I will get the replacement happen ASAP.] Thank you for pointing out a reasonable direction to look into, @Heptite :)

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a rhetorical question. If you know of any way external to Vim to obtain this information, it can probably be used by Vim to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Heptite, I think I found a tentative solution, but failed to produce a reasonable succinct Vim function/conditionals to do the real job. I had trouble to: 1. fetch the results from Command Prompt back to Vim; 2. to issue process the displayed result through RegEX, and 3. to implement a "listening process" on Vim that will be triggered when it detects the change of screen resolution.